# CICS Webservice as API where CICS is service provider

Tags: cobol, mainframe, webservice-client, cics

I have business logic in CICS, we want to replace maps/ mapsets with distributed systems, so we want our CICS programs to provide service and have distributed system (to replace maps/ mapsets) that sends request and receive response from CICS are processing. This is for Legacy payment application and is non-SSP environment.

As first step, I am trying to submit JCL that creates WSDL and WSBIND files using CICS webservice assistant tool (DHFLS2DS) but I am not sure about the parameters to be passed, that executes BPXBATCH.

```
//JAVAPRG1 EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,REGION=400M, 
// PARM=('SH &PATHPREF/usr/lpp/cicsts/&USSDIR/lib/wsdl/DFHLS2WS ', X 
// '&JAVADIR &USSDIR &TMPDIR./&TMPFILE. &SERVICE &PATHPREF')
```

Can someone please help with required parameters to be passed to execute CICS webservice assistant tool?

Comment: Parameters are described in detail in the documentation for [DFHLS2WS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.3?topic=assistant-dfhls2ws-high-level-language-wsdl-conversion). What parameters exactly are you unclear about?

Answer (score 6):

Not answering your parameter question, but commenting on the JCL.

```
//JAVAPRG1 EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,REGION=400M, 
//*.+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7..    
// PARM=('SH &PATHPREF/usr/lpp/cicsts/&USSDIR/lib/wsdl/DFHLS2WS ',     X 
// '&JAVADIR &USSDIR &TMPDIR./&TMPFILE. &SERVICE &PATHPREF')
```

Note that the *maximum length* of the `PARM=` data is *100 characters*. This is a *JCL limit*. Your PARM will probably exceed 100 characters after symbolic parameter resolution.

BPXPATCH has implemented the `//STDPARM DD` statement as an alternative way to pass parameters. There is a limit of 65536 characters on `//STDPARM`. See here for details: [Running shell scripts or executable files under MVS environments - Topic BPXBATCH](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=environments-bpxbatch#bpxbatr).

The modified JCL for the step would look smoething like this:

```
//JAVAPRG1 EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,REGION=400M 
//... put any other DD statements for BPXBATCH phere
//...
//STDPARM   DD *
  SH 
  &PATHPREF/usr/lpp/cicsts/&USSDIR/lib/wsdl/DFHLS2WS 
  &JAVADIR &USSDIR 
  &TMPDIR./&TMPFILE. &SERVICE &PATHPREF
/*
```

But there is the problem of resolving the JCL symbolic parameters within SYSIN data, which is not done by default. You need to enable symbolic parameter resolution by changing the DD statement to look like this:

```
//STDPARM DD *,SYMBOLS=(JCLONLY)
```

Additionally, you need tell which parameters you want to be eligible for resolution in SYSIN data. This is done with the following statement before your `EXEC` statement, and before any symbolic parameter that you might `SET`. Best place is immediately following the `JOB` statement.

```
//       EXPORT  SYMLIST=*
```

Note that your systems programmer must have allowed this for the job class your job will run in. The job class must have been set to `SYSSYM=ALLOW`.

The final JCL looks like this:

```
//jobname  JOB ....
//... any job level parameters you need go here
//*
//         EXPORT SYMLIST=*
//*
//... any additional symbolic parameters are set here
//*
//JAVAPRG1 EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,REGION=400M 
//... put any other DD statements, BPXBATCH requires here
//...
//STDPARM   DD *,SYMBOLS=(JCLONLY)
SH 
  &PATHPREF/usr/lpp/cicsts/&USSDIR/lib/wsdl/DFHLS2WS 
  &JAVADIR &USSDIR 
  &TMPDIR./&TMPFILE. &SERVICE &PATHPREF
/*
```

**Warning**: I have not actually run that JCL, since I do not know what all the symbolic parameters are set to in your environment.

Final note: Enabling Symbolic parameter resolution in SYSIN data doesn't look like a straight forward process, does it?. IBM had to implement this in a way that guaranteed not to break any existing job (JCL). Once you get used to it, it is nevertheless a very useful thing, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The JOB Symbolic parameters and SYSIN parameters are explained in this official IBM [document](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.3?topic=assistant-dfhls2ws-high-level-language-wsdl-conversion)

Mainly, we need to check the location of DFHLS2WS program present in the Z/OS Unix file path and pass in the symbolic parameter - JAVADIR and we can use the default parameters for the remaining symbolic parameters unless you have a requirement to change it.

Note : all parameters are not required.

Please pass the SYSIN parameters as per your application and requirement. The significance of all the parameters are explained in the above document.

Comment: Your wording *OMVS Unix region* is a bit strange. There is not such thing in z/OS. But, there is a standard UNIX like **file system** besides the legacy MVS data sets. Program DFHLS2WS is residing in this UNIX file system on z/OS, and you need to specify the path to it (if this path is not in the standard PATH set forth by the shell).

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the above answer.